# Is random seed a hyper-parameter to tune in training deep neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, hyperparameter

For building deep neural networks, there are a lot of random components in each training. On one hand, I feel it is uncanny to "tune" random seed. But in my experience, some random seed just works better than others ...

So, Is random seed a hyper-parameter to tune in training deep neural network?

Comment: Whenever I play blackjack, I like to "tune" the random seed of the dealer so that I get to 21 in the first few cards.

Comment: @Sycorax thanks for your comments but I am not sure I fully understand your analogy or joke...

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/341619/why-is-it-valid-to-use-cv-to-set-parameters-and-hyperparameters-but-not-seeds

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your training has large changes in performance due to the random seed, then it is unstable. This is an undesirable trait. Testing different random seeds can in this sense be useful to check stability. But picking a model from a given random seed which happens to do better on the validation set does not guarantee better performance on unseen data.

Comment: We can tune seed on validation and report the result on the test set. Similart to other hyperparameters that are optimised on the validation set.

Comment: Why do you think that would give better performance on the test set? IE, why would it not be just overfitting to the validation set?