# R prcomp and KNN different correct classification rate

Tags: r, classification, pca, k-nearest-neighbour

I'm performing a classification task using KNN and PCA to pre-process the data.

The dataset contains 101 continuous variables and the column of the labels (here the link to download the data [filebin.net/fy2238g063hhijsf](http://filebin.net/fy2238g063hhijsf))

```
> dim(train)
[1]  33 102
> unique(train[,1])
[1] Crete      Peloponese Other     
Levels: Crete Other Peloponese
```

I've applied PCA on the dataset as below:

```
> train.pca <- prcomp(train[,-1],center = TRUE,scale. = TRUE)
> summary(train.pca)
Importance of components:
                          PC1    PC2    PC3    PC4     PC5    PC6     PC7    PC8     PC9    PC10    PC11
Standard deviation     6.2499 5.5934 4.3538 2.5857 1.53128 1.1457 0.88391 0.5223 0.37085 0.27148 0.20914
Proportion of Variance 0.3867 0.3098 0.1877 0.0662 0.02322 0.0130 0.00774 0.0027 0.00136 0.00073 0.00043
Cumulative Proportion  0.3867 0.6965 0.8842 0.9504 0.97360 0.9866 0.99433 0.9970 0.99840 0.99912 0.99956
                          PC12    PC13    PC14    PC15    PC16    PC17    PC18    PC19    PC20    PC21
Standard deviation     0.10622 0.09947 0.07317 0.06188 0.05741 0.04700 0.04026 0.03675 0.03154 0.03029
Proportion of Variance 0.00011 0.00010 0.00005 0.00004 0.00003 0.00002 0.00002 0.00001 0.00001 0.00001
Cumulative Proportion  0.99967 0.99977 0.99982 0.99986 0.99989 0.99991 0.99993 0.99994 0.99995 0.99996
                          PC22    PC23    PC24    PC25    PC26    PC27    PC28    PC29    PC30    PC31
Standard deviation     0.02676 0.02422 0.02301 0.01986 0.01969 0.01836 0.01757 0.01506 0.01304 0.01241
Proportion of Variance 0.00001 0.00001 0.00001 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
Cumulative Proportion  0.99997 0.99997 0.99998 0.99998 0.99999 0.99999 0.99999 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000
                          PC32      PC33
Standard deviation     0.01016 3.344e-13
Proportion of Variance 0.00000 0.000e+00
Cumulative Proportion  1.00000 1.000e+00
```

and I chose to keep only 4 principal components. I then calculated the principal components scores for measures in the validation set.

```
validation.pca <- predict(train.pca,newdata = validation[,-1])
```

I then tried a few values of the parameter k to fit a KNN model.

```
> set.seed(1234)
> #tune k using transformed data
> ccr.tnx <-numeric(25)
> for(j in 1:25)
+ {
+   pred.class.tnx<-knn(train.pca$x[,1:4], 
+                   validation.pca[,1:4], 
+                   train[,1], 
+                   k=j)
+   ccr.tnx[j]<-sum((pred.class.tnx==validation[,1]))/length(pred.class.tnx)
+   print(ccr.tnx[j])
+ }
[1] 0.8823529
[1] 0.8823529
[1] 0.7058824
[1] 0.8235294
[1] 0.8235294
[1] 0.8235294
[1] 0.6470588
[1] 0.7647059
[1] 0.7058824
[1] 0.6470588
[1] 0.8235294
[1] 0.7647059
[1] 0.7647059
[1] 0.7058824
[1] 0.7647059
[1] 0.6470588
[1] 0.6470588
[1] 0.7647059
[1] 0.7647059
[1] 0.7058824
[1] 0.6470588
[1] 0.5882353
[1] 0.5294118
[1] 0.7058824
[1] 0.7058824
```

From the result above I chose to use k=2 with

```
> ccr.tnx[2]
[1] 0.8823529
```

I then tried to fit the model again with k=2 as below

```
> set.seed(1234)
> pred.class.tnx.2<-knn(train.pca$x[,1:4], 
+                     validation.pca[,1:4], 
+                     train[,1], 
+                     k=2)
> sum((pred.class.tnx.2==validation[,1]))/length(pred.class.tnx.2)
[1] 0.6470588
```

But I get a different correct classification rate! How is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried setting the random seed *inside* the for loop?

Comment: @Tim you are my saviour! that was the problem, with the seed set inside the loop the results are consistent.

Comment: Notice that there is 23% discrepancy between runs with two seeds. Unwillingly you cross-validated your results with different training and validation sets and it shown that there is a big variability in your results, so they are probably not very trustworthy.

Comment: @Tim could you expand a bit on your last point? I'm not entirely sure I understand why I have used different training and validation sets. Following your suggestion now I get the same result within the loop and outside of it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't use this kind of stuff in R for a while. In knn there's not much randomization going on, do I assumed it randomly splits your data. This doesn't seem to be the case, but nonetheless, if changing seed has that profound impact, this suggests problems.

Comment: @Tim no worries. It's just that the seed is the same in the two instances. `set.seed(1234)`

Comment: I'm afraid you may be missing the point. I'm saying that it's worrying that when you used different seeds you got different results.

Comment: right, I see what you mean now. what would you think about doing some sort of cross-validation for tuning k using different seeds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comment, the problem with your code was that you used a single seed at the beginning of the `for`-loop, so at each step after the random number generator got called, the seed incremented. The solution would be either to manually set the seeds at each step, or at each step record the seed that was used.

The bigger problem, not mentioned by you, is however that *when* you unintentionally used different seeds for different runs of the algorithm, you validated the algorithm's sensitivity to the seeds. [$k$-NN algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) does not really use randomization, the only point where it comes to the algorithm is when [breaking the ties](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/breaking-ties-k-nn-classification-nicholas-pylypiw). If different seeds give you results that can differ by 23%, then this means that it is widely unstable. This discrepancy means that the algorithm has [settled in local minimum](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/341610/is-it-fair-to-set-a-seed-in-a-random-forest-regression-to-yield-the-highest-ac][1]), so the recommended solution would usually be to use some kind of regularization (in $k$-NN this would mean using higher number of neighbours $k$). Of course, in some cases, [you can](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/341619/why-is-it-valid-to-use-cv-to-set-parameters-and-hyperparameters-but-not-seeds) treat random seed as a hyperparameter to tune, but since this is a clear signal of overfitting, it should be carefully considered, and used *after* trying more standard approaches like regularization.

Comment: I understand your point now Tim, thanks. What I had in mind though was to calculate the error rate for different values of k on the validation set and for different seeds. Then I was thinking to take the average error rate for a given k  using the error rates obtained with different seeds. Finally choosing k with the lowest average error rate. Would you say that it's a reasonable way of going about it?

Comment: @alessandro but then you would be using the average of the predictions over different seeds as your final prediction? Otherwise, the method would not be consistent with your usage. On another hand, if you did that, this would be very computationally intensive--why not consider other method?

Comment: I would take the averages over different seeds just to tune the parameter k that minimises the misclassification rate on the validation set. would you agree with that approach?

Comment: @alessandro but the average tells you nothing, e.g. if you pick the "worst" seed, the performance would be worst then the average you calculated...

Comment: it makes sense, but what about if I don't set the seed and let R pick one at 'random'?

Comment: @alessandro then your performance can be better, or worse, at random, depending on the seed. It doesn't solve the problem that the predictions are unstable.

Comment: Would it be at least an indication of how volatile the predictions are?

Comment: @alessandro if you want to asses how volatile the predictions are, you should rather look at the variance, then mean. Average of errors wouldn't tell you much about their variability. Your choices are: (a) do something to reduce variability (feature engineering, some form of regularization e.g. $k>2$), of (b) find the "best" random seed and stick with it--just make sure that you don't have data leak and you are not overfitting to the validation set.

Comment: sure I see, thanks! I'll try what you suggest.